# Saving a PNG or JPG image to Photos in iOS via PhoneGap

Tags: ios, image, cordova, base64, photos

I am new to PhoneGap and would like to know how to save an in-App image to Photos in iOS.

While I was able to use

```
navigator.camera.getPicture
```

with options

```
quality:50, destinationType:Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,saveToPhotoAlbum: true
```

to save a picture taken with the camera to Photos, I am now trying to find out how to save an in-App image to Photos.

Consider the following PhoneGap - Cordova page where the element myPhoto holds imagedata such as "data:image/jpeg;base64,"...

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Save Image</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


    function savePicture(){
                    //this is where the magic would happen
                    //how can I save myPhoto to Photos?
                    //output imageData to a jpg or png file which would show up in Photos?
    }

        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="savePicture();">Save Photo</button> <br>
            <input type="hidden" name="myPhoto" id="myPhoto" value="">
</body>
</html>
```

**Question:**

What should savePicture() do to save the imagedata from myPhoto to Photos in iOS via Phonegap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently came across the following Phonegap plugin for saving Canvas images to Photos in iOS:
https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin

Follow the readme [**instructions**](https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin) for importing the plugin and then you can use it the following way:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Save Image</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../Canvas2Image/Canvas2ImagePlugin.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        var canvas2ImagePlugin; //devgeeks plugin for saving canvas images to photo gallery

        function onDeviceReady() {
             canvas2ImagePlugin = window.plugins.canvas2ImagePlugin;
         }

        function savePicture(){
            canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(function(msg){console.log(msg);},function(err){console.log(err);},'mycanvas');
         }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500px" height="300px"> <strong>[Your browser can not show this example.]</strong> </canvas>
        <button onclick="savePicture();">Save Photo</button> <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i used your code and procedure but i am not able to get the solution. can you help me to find it out?

Comment: Yes i dint get solution.. i got THREAD WARNING: Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could try the plugin I wrote for IOS (If you want to save a canvas element to photogallery, you could get the dataURI of the canvas the use the **downloadWithUrl** method below). Hope it works for you.

here is the git link: https://github.com/Nomia/ImgDownloader

Short Example:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady);

//google logo url
url = 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png';

onDeviceReady = function(){
    cordova.plugins.imgDownloader.downloadWithUrl(url,function(){
        alert("success");
    },function(){
        alert("error");
    });        
}

//also you can try dataUri like: 1px gif
//url = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7'
```

you can also save a local file to image gallery use the **download** method

Comment: thanks !!! this worked for me . the only issue i faced was , i had space in my url . anyways , saved my time :)

Comment: After HOURS of trying to get file + fileTransfer working on ios (Android is ok), I gave up and said well, let's give this little plugin a shot... 10 sec later, everything works. You're awesome @Nimbosa !

Comment: You sir are THE MAN! Works perfectly with almost zero effort. Wish I found this hours ago. :)